# How to post silent notification using onesignal rest api C#

Tags: c#, android, ios, asp.net-core, onesignal

I am beginner in using this api and it's services. I have tried lots of thing but nothing worked for me, Just wanted to push silent notification. Any suggestion will be appreciated and Thanks in advance.

```
        private static readonly string oneSignalUrl = "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications";
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendNotification(string playerId, string notificationAppId, string notificationSecretKey)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(oneSignalUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", "Basic " + notificationSecretKey);
            var model = new DictionaryDTO { aps = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "content-available", 1 } }, acme1 = "logout" };
            var content = GetContent(notificationAppId, model, playerId); 
            var response = await client.PostAsync(oneSignalUrl, content);
            return response;
        }
        public StringContent GetContent(string notificationAppId, DictionaryDTO model, string playerId)
        {
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                app_id = notificationAppId,
                contents = new
                {
                    en = "Testing the push notification functionality",
                    model
                },
                include_player_ids = new string[] { playerId }
            }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return content;
        }
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: "aps": {
    alert = "Testing the push notification functionality";
    "mutable-content" = 1;
    sound = default;
}, "custom": {
    "collapse_id" = "260E3965-40B1-4685-AA7F-BD94C41D7670";
    i = "89909d19-4cd9-47b9-939a-d74504aee7b6";
}

Getting the above json string as message of notification while only message("Testing the push notification functionality") should be pushed instead of json string  also it's not as silent one. Please suggest if I am missing anything.